# Use a separate FlutterFragmentActivity in a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have been struggling with a problem. We use the following plugins in our Flutter project:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/truecaller_sdk
2. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk

The problem here is that Truecaller wants us to inherit FlutterFragmentActivity in my MainActivity file, and while branch and its deep links work with Fragment Activity, they don't work when the app is terminated. So, when my MainActivity class extends FlutterFragmentActivity, then on clicking on the deep links generated in Branch, my data is lost, hence the redirection cannot be performed, but it works perfectly with FlutterActivity.

is there any way that I could use FlutterFragmentActivity separately for truecaller while still inheriting FlutterActivity in my MainActivity class?

Comment: did you find solution to this?